# Raw character input to String

Tags: java

I'm trying to make a chat rendering the user input using Graphics2D. For this, i need to get the *raw* (every character or letter the user types on his keyboard) user input to a String. 
Currently i'm using

```
if (input.isKeyPressed(input.KEY_A)) {
    this.text += "a";
}
```

However, this requires me to register every key (and some characters are not available).

How do i get the raw input to a String?

Edit: I'm using the Slick2d library

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know which library you are using right now, but in Java Swing you can use:

```
char typedCharacter = KeyEvent.getKeyChar();
```

The idea is that you should "listen" to key events, instead of checking continuously if one of the key's is pressed. Try to find out how to do that, using the library you are using.

Comment: I'm using Slick2d.
I found this:     
`@Override
    public void keyPressed(int key, char c) {
        if (c == 'a') {
            color = Color.black;
        }
    }`
from [link](http://slick.javaunlimited.net/viewtopic.php?t=3482), but i can't figure how to implement it

Comment: That peace of code you linked is pretty straightforward, I can't help more than that. Just try do imitate what they do in the linked code. Note that the keyPressed method should be written in a class that extends `BasicGame`.

Comment: It does, and i did put it in the class. I just don't know how to invoke the method, and what parameters to give it

Answer (score 0):

You'll need a `KeyListener` that implements the `keyTyped(KeyEvent e)` method. In that method then you'll be able to do `e.getKeyChar()` as one of the other answers is suggesting.